# Javascript to PHP conversion

Tags: javascript, php

I've got one javascript port of the libphonenumber package and it has the function below:

```
function cleanPhone(a){
    a=a.replace(/[^\d\+]/g,"");
    return a="+"==a.substr(0,1)?"+"+a.replace(/[^\d]/g,""):a.replace(/[^\d]/g,"")
}
```

I'm trying to convert this function to PHP and was wondering if this is correct:

```
function cleanPhone($a) {
    $a = preg_replace('/[^\d\+]/g',"", $a);
    return $a = "+" == substr(0,1)?"+"+ preg_replace('/[^\d]/g',"", $a) : preg_replace('/[^\d]/g',"", $a);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: *I did Sam, and got a busy signal* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: yes, I have and got this first: `Unknown modifier 'g' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g is not a valid modifier in PCRE (the regex implementation PHP uses)
>   because it's simply not needed; preg_replace() will perform global
>   replacements by default. You'll find the modifier in true Perl regex
>   as well as JavaScript regex, but not in PCRE.

I would write it more clearly:

```
function cleanPhone($a) {
    $a = preg_replace('/[^\d\+]/', "", $a);
    if(substr($a, 0, 1) == "+"){
       return "+" + preg_replace('/[^\d]/', "", $a); 
    }else{
      return preg_replace('/[^\d]/',"", $a);
    }
}
```

Also notice you were missing the variable identifier for the substring method `substr($string, $startIndex, [$length])`

The minified version using a [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) should also work:

```
function cleanPhone($a) {
    $a = preg_replace('/[^\d\+]/',"", $a);
    return ("+" == substr($a,0,1))?"+"+ preg_replace('/[^\d]/',"", $a) : preg_replace('/[^\d]/',"", $a);
}
```

Comment: `Unknown modifier 'g' `

Comment: Check now, you didn't need the g modifier